# Insert in SQLiteOpenHelper dosen't work correctly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with SQLite in android , I tried a simple insert in a table but I have an exception and in the exception I read this :

```
INSERT INTO Biblio(Auteur,Image,Livre) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

this is my method :

```
public void AddBook(Bibliothèque bibliothèque)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    //this.open();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_Auteur,bibliothèque.getNomAuteur());
    values.put(KEY_Livre,bibliothèque.getNomLivre());
    values.put(Key_photo,bibliothèque.geturiimage().toString());
    db.insert("Biblio",null,values);
    db.close();

}
```

and this is my variables:

```
    private static final String TABLE_Nom = "Biblio";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_Auteur = "Auteur";
    private static final String KEY_Livre = "Livre";
    private static final String Key_photo="Image";
```

the problem I don't know why but db.insert invert beetween Image and Livre and because of that I have an exception and I don't know why the value that I insert are ? ? ? in debug I can see that the value are correct ! . normaly the true expression must be :

```
INSERT INTO Biblio(Auteur,Livre,Image) VALUES (cc,test,(uri of picture))
```

this is the entire exception :

```
2927-2927/com.example.myapplication4.app E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Biblio has no column named Livre
05-15 02:53:54.436    2927-2927/com.example.myapplication4.app E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting Auteur=gsopfkgop Image=content://media/external/images/media/10 Livre=fhoksgkp
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Biblio has no column named Livre (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Biblio(Auteur,Image,Livre) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: post the entire LogCat of the exception.

Comment: have you inserted `Livre` column later on ?

Comment: in all code I have just one insert of the tree Strings.

Comment: @NoseProgrammer post you create table query it's cannot create that collume that why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE This Query to Create Table.

```
 db.execSQL
    ("CREATE TABLE Biblio (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,Auteur TEXT,Livre TEXT,Image TEXT)");
```

then You have to insert record using Below code:

```
public void AddBook(Bibliothèque bibliothèque)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    //this.open();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(Auteur,bibliothèque.getNomAuteur());
    values.put(Livre,bibliothèque.getNomLivre());
    values.put(Image,bibliothèque.geturiimage().toString());
    db.insert("Biblio",null,values);
    db.close();

}
```

I hope its useful to you..

Comment: yeah it's the solution now I don't get any exception Thank you so much !

Comment: I forget to say that in values.put , all the first argument I write it with " "

Answer (score 0):

```
2927-2927/com.example.myapplication4.app E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Biblio has no column named Livre
```

Your table doesn't have a column named Livre, either you have a spelling mistake here, in your table creation code, or you haven't defined a column named Livre.

Comment: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_Nom+" ("+id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+
               KEY_Auteur+ " TEXT, "+KEY_Livre+" TEXT, "+Key_photo+" TEXT );");` this is the code and it's insert that invert two of my fieleds I don't know why look please at the two formula I write in the subject

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reinstall your app? 
Also, if your db schema has been changed after your app installed in your test device, you have to increase db version parameter to invoke onUpdate() method or reinstall your app to invoke onCreate().

Comment: Don't post comments as answers, they will be ruthlessly deleted. Try to suggest three more edits then you will have enough reputation to to post comments.